# TensorFlow Spark-pyspark rdd transformation return RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark

I'm tryng to use pyspark to execute TensorFlow in a collection of images but I'm getting this error when I applied a transformation in an RDD.
The error is inside the function **run_inference_on_image**
I've got the error using "local" and "spark://master.spark.tfm:7077"

This is the trace of the error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/utad/PycharmProjects/TensorFlowMirFlickr/ClasificacionImagenes.py
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/06/04 00:47:16 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
('Model already downloaded:', '/home/utad/TFM/model/inception-2015-12-05.tgz', posix.stat_result(st_mode=33204, st_ino=709599, st_dev=2049, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=88931400, st_atime=1496482158, st_mtime=1496482158, st_ctime=1496482158))
('rddImagenes: ', [['http://host.images.tfm:8000/mirflickr/im1.jpg'], ['http://host.images.tfm:8000/mirflickr/im10.jpg'], ['http://host.images.tfm:8000/mirflickr/im100.jpg']])
17/06/04 00:47:24 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 163, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 54, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 169, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 454, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/home/utad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/home/utad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/utad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/home/utad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/utad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
...
...
...
  File "/home/utad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/utad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/home/utad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Launched with spark-submit gives me this Driver stacktrace

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1965)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Módulos a usar
from pyspark import SparkContext
import os.path
from six.moves import urllib
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import re
import numpy as np


# **************************************************************************************
# Configuración proceso
# Modelo lo bajamos de la red y lo guardamos en directorio local
MODEL_URL = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz'
model_dir = '/home/utad/TFM/model'

# Simulamos que las imagenes las obtenermos de un servicio web
IMAGES_INDEX_URL = 'http://host.images.tfm:8000/mirflickr/'

# Otros datos
numero_imagenes_proceso = 3  # Número total de imágenes a procesar
lote_size = 1  # Número de imágenes por lote
max_etiquetas = 5  # Número máximo de etiquetas por imagen

# Fin Configuración proceso
# **************************************************************************************


# Obtenemos modelo
def get_tensorflow_model():
    # Download and extract model tar file
    filename = MODEL_URL.split('/')[-1]
    filepath = os.path.join(model_dir, filename)
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        filepath2, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(MODEL_URL, filepath)
        print("filepath2", filepath2)
        statinfo = os.stat(filepath)
        print('Succesfully downloaded', filename, statinfo.st_size, 'bytes.')
        tarfile.open(filepath, 'r:gz').extractall(model_dir)
    else:
        print('Model already downloaded:', filepath, os.stat(filepath))


# Obtenida de classify_image.py del github de TensorFlow
class NodeLookup(object):
    """Converts integer node IDs to human readable labels."""

    def __init__(self, label_lookup_path=None, uid_lookup_path=None):
        if not label_lookup_path:
            label_lookup_path = os.path.join(
                model_dir, 'imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt')
        if not uid_lookup_path:
            uid_lookup_path = os.path.join(
                model_dir, 'imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt')
            self.node_lookup = self.load(label_lookup_path, uid_lookup_path)

    def load(self, label_lookup_path, uid_lookup_path):
        """Loads a human readable English name for each softmax node.

        Args:
            label_lookup_path: string UID to integer node ID.
            uid_lookup_path: string UID to human-readable string.

        Returns:
            dict from integer node ID to human-readable string.
        """
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(uid_lookup_path):
            tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', uid_lookup_path)
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(label_lookup_path):
            tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', label_lookup_path)

        # Loads mapping from string UID to human-readable string
        proto_as_ascii_lines = tf.gfile.GFile(uid_lookup_path).readlines()
        uid_to_human = {}
        p = re.compile(r'[n\d]*[ \S,]*')
        for line in proto_as_ascii_lines:
            parsed_items = p.findall(line)
            uid = parsed_items[0]
            human_string = parsed_items[2]
            uid_to_human[uid] = human_string

        # Loads mapping from string UID to integer node ID.
        node_id_to_uid = {}
        proto_as_ascii = tf.gfile.GFile(label_lookup_path).readlines()
        for line in proto_as_ascii:
            if line.startswith('  target_class:'):
                target_class = int(line.split(': ')[1])
            if line.startswith('  target_class_string:'):
                target_class_string = line.split(': ')[1]
                node_id_to_uid[target_class] = target_class_string[1:-2]

        # Loads the final mapping of integer node ID to human-readable string
        node_id_to_name = {}
        for key, val in node_id_to_uid.items():
            if val not in uid_to_human:
                tf.logging.fatal('Failed to locate: %s', val)
            name = uid_to_human[val]
            node_id_to_name[key] = name

        return node_id_to_name

    def id_to_string(self, node_id):
        if node_id not in self.node_lookup:
            return ''
        return self.node_lookup[node_id]


def run_inference_on_image(sess, image, lookup):
    """Hacemos inferencia sobre la imagen.

    Args:
        sess: TensorFlow Session
        image: Imagen a leer
        lookup: node lookup obtenido previamente

    Returns:
      (image ID, image URL, scores),
      where scores is a list of (human-readable node names, score) pairs
    """
    image_data = urllib.request.urlopen(image).read()
    print("Image: ", image_data)
    # Some useful tensors:
    # 'softmax:0': A tensor containing the normalized prediction across
    #   1000 labels.
    # 'pool_3:0': A tensor containing the next-to-last layer containing 2048
    #   float description of the image.
    # 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': A tensor containing a string providing JPEG
    #   encoding of the image.
    # Runs the softmax tensor by feeding the image_data as input to the graph.
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')
    try:
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
        print("predictions: ", predictions)
    except:
        # Handle problems with malformed JPEG files
        return image, None
    predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)
    top_k = predictions.argsort()[-max_etiquetas:][::-1]
    print("top_k predictions: ", top_k)
    scores = []
    for node_id in top_k:
        if node_id not in lookup:
            human_string = ''
        else:
            human_string = lookup[node_id]
        score = predictions[node_id]
        scores.append((human_string, score))
    print ("tupla: ", image, scores)
    return image, scores


def apply_inference_on_batch(lote, lookup_bc):
    """Apply inference to a batch of images.

    We do not explicitly tell TensorFlow to use a GPU.
    It is able to choose between CPU and GPU based on its guess of which will be faster.
    """
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
        print("Apply")
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        print("Graph_def: ", graph_def)

        graph_def.ParseFromString(model_data_bc.value)
        print("Graph_def1: ", graph_def)
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        print("TF: ", tf)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            print("Sesion: ", sess)
            print("Lote: ", lote)
            print("Node_lookup: ", lookup_bc)
            labeled = [run_inference_on_image(sess, image, lookup_bc.value) for image in
                       lote]
            return [tup for tup in labeled if tup[1] is not None]


# Función auxiliar para obtener el nombre de una imagen.
def obtener_nombre_imagen(x):
    return IMAGES_INDEX_URL + x.split('<')[1].split('>')[1]


# Iniciamos SparkContext
# sc = SparkContext('spark://master.spark.tfm:7077', 'TensorFlow')
sc = SparkContext('local')
get_tensorflow_model()

# Cargamos el modelo y lo distribuimos
model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'classify_image_graph_def.pb')
with tf.gfile.FastGFile(model_path, 'rb') as f:
    model_data = f.read()
model_data_bc = sc.broadcast(model_data)

# Distribuimos node lookup para ser utilizado en los workers
node_lookup = NodeLookup().node_lookup
node_lookup_bc = sc.broadcast(node_lookup)

# Obtenemos una lista de las imágenes a procesar y las agrupamos en lotes
imagenes = urllib.request.urlopen(IMAGES_INDEX_URL).read().split('<li>')[2:numero_imagenes_proceso+2]
lote_imagenes = [imagenes[i:i + lote_size] for i in range(0, len(imagenes), lote_size)]

# Paralelizamos los lotes de imagenes y procesamos
rddImagenes = sc.parallelize(lote_imagenes).map(lambda x: map(obtener_nombre_imagen, x))
print("rddImagenes: ", rddImagenes.collect())
imagenes_etiquetadas = rddImagenes.flatMap(lambda x: apply_inference_on_batch(x, node_lookup_bc))
# imagenes_etiquetadas = rddImagenes.flatMap(lambda x: x[0].split("/"))

l = imagenes_etiquetadas.collect()
```

Please, any advice about what is going on?

**Edit**: I've just discovered that the problem is when calling to "`image_data = urllib.request.urlopen(image).read()`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, or at least I've found a workaround.

I've changed:

```
from six.moves import urllib
```

for:

```
import urllib
```

I don't know why urllib from six is not working, but this solves my problem.